# Master detail android on phone and tablet

Tags: android, listview, android-framelayout

I want to make a news system in my android application using the master/detail design, but I'm a bit confused how to make it work from smartphone to tablet.

[image: design preview]

tablet : one linearlayout for the listview(master) and one framelayout

smartphone: only one framelayout with master and detail as fragment?

Do you have a better solution?

Comment: There is exact this sample at android dev tuts https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

Comment: thx, i should check the docs before posting -_-, sorry

Comment: This article describes how to use master/detail flow http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui.html